# Can accountant use API for non-QBO-Plus customers?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online, qbo3

It's mentioned in the docs, "***Tracking business segments and class tracking in general is available with QuickBooks Online Plus, only***".

**Question**: As an accountant, can I use the API to review transactions for non-plus a customer?